# Pass table value type to SQL Server stored procedure via Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I created a user-defined table type in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.TestType AS TABLE 
(
    ColumnA int,
    ColumnB nvarchar(500)
)
```

And I'm using a stored procedure to insert records into the database:

```
create procedure [dbo].[sp_Test_CustomType]
   @testing TestType READONLY
as
    insert into [dbo].[myTable]
        select ColumnA, ColumnB 
        from @testing
```

And I would like to use EF to execute this stored procedure, but here's the problem: how can I pass a user defined table to the stored procedure?

I tried adding the stored procedure to the model, but I'm unable to find the desired stored procedure in the updated context.

What I'm trying to do is to execute a bulk insert to a table, here's the method that I'm currently using:

```
List<items> itemToInsertToDB = //fetchItems;

foreach(items i in itemToInsertToDB)
{
     context.sp_InsertToTable(i.ColumnA, i.ColumnB)
}
```

Currently, I use a `foreach` loop to loop through the list to insert item to DB, but if the list have a lot of items, then there will be a performance issue, so, I'm thinking of passing a list to the stored procedure and do the insert inside.

So how to solve this problem? or are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/78607b/using-table-valued-parameters-in-entity-framework/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Lets say you want to send a table with a single column of GUIDs.

First we need to create a structure using [SqlMetaData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlmetadata(v=vs.110).aspx) which represents the schema of the table (columns).

The below code demonstrates one column named "Id" of the GUID is the SQL stored procedure parameter table type

```
var tableSchema = new List<SqlMetaData>(1)
{
  new SqlMetaData("Id", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)
}.ToArray();
```

Next you create a list of records that match the schema using [SqlDataRecord](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqldatarecord(v=vs.110).aspx).

The below code demonstrates how to add the items inside a list using the above created schema. Create a new SqlDataRecord for each of the items in the list. Replace SetGuid with the corresponding type and Replace Guid.NewGuid() as the corresponding value.
Repeat new SqlDataRecord for each item and add them to a List

```
var tableRow = new SqlDataRecord(tableSchema);
tableRow.SetGuid(0, Guid.NewGuid());
var table = new List<SqlDataRecord>(1)
{
  tableRow
};
```

Then create the [SqlParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var parameter = new SqlParameter();
parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
parameter.ParameterName = "@UserIds"; //@UserIds is the stored procedure parameter name
parameter.TypeName = "{Your stored procedure type name}"
parameter.Value = table;

var parameters = new SqlParameter[1]
{
  parameter
};
```

Then simply call the stored procedure by using the [Database.SqlQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545(v=vs.113).aspx).

```
IEnumerable<ReturnType> result;
using (var myContext = new DbContext())
{
  result = myContext.Database.SqlQuery<User>("GetUsers @UserIds", parameters)
    .ToList();         // calls the stored procedure
    // ToListAsync();  // Async
{
```

In SQL Server, create your User-Defined Table Type (I suffix them with TTV, Table Typed Value):

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UniqueidentifiersTTV] AS TABLE(
  [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
)
GO
```

Then specify the type as a parameter (don't forget, Table Type Values have to be readonly!):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUsers] (
  @UserIds [UniqueidentifiersTTV] READONLY
) AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON

  SELECT u.* -- Just an example :P
  FROM [dbo].[Users] u
  INNER JOIN @UserIds ids On u.Id = ids.Id
END
```

Comment: Where did the.SetGuid come from ?

Comment: [SqlDataRecord.SetGuid()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqldatarecord.setguid(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: 1) mouseover `result` in the debugger will throw bogus exception "stored procedure Must declare the scalar variable" because it's trying to evaluate the parameter twice. Use `.ToList()` (as above) to avoid this. 2) I was getting exception "The table type parameter '@table' must have a valid type name." which was fixed by specifying the parameter type: `parameter.TypeName = "dbo.TestType"` (with "dbo" prefix)

Comment: @BurnsBA if you have a problem with your code, posting in a comment is not the proper solution.  Instead use the `Ask A Question` button, show your code, ask the question and reference this question/answer.

Comment: As mentioned in the [documentation for table valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters) "You must specify a type name for the table-valued parameter by using the TypeName property of a SqlParameter".

Comment: I don't think BurnsBA is trying to ask a question about the code. I think he's trying to suggest improvements. At least, that's how his comment reads to me.

Comment: @ErikPhilips what would the sproc look like here? Do we need to duplicate the creation of the type in the stored procedure? (if not exists)

Comment: Hi. First of all, thanks for your solution. I used it, but did not work for me. I spent about 2 hours figuring out what is wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46908349/mssql-not-passing-user-defined-table-type-using-sp-executesql. The problem was, that  I forgot to pass the parameter while calling "myContext.Database.SqlQuery<User>("GetUsers", parameters)". It would be great if you update your answer, so it looks like this "myContext.Database.SqlQuery<User>("GetUsers @UserIds", parameters)". Thank, Martin

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you not using Stored Procedure to insert bulk data, but just rely to Entity Framework insert mechanism.

```
List<items> itemToInsertToDB = //fetchItems;
foreach(items i in itemToInsertToDB)
{
    TestType t = new TestType() { ColumnA = i.ColumnA, ColumnB = i.ColumnB };
    context.TestTypes.Add(t);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Entity framework will smartly perform those insertion in single transaction and (usually) in single query execution, which will almost equal to executing stored procedure. This is better rather than relying on stored procedure just to insert bulk of data.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I know that Entity framework have a function called "bulkinsert" https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/ , but I was required to use stored procedure for easier maintenance.

Comment: EF works well unless you're in a very complicated distributed transaction scenario using transaction scopes.

Comment: EF is not that smart.  Save changes executes a transaction, but it issues individual insert statements for each entity inserted. That's why the BulkInsert is a separate, paid library, although older, free versions exists.  By default, EF will issue a separate insert statement for each item inserted. The performance is horrible.  For bulk inserts, use SqlBulkCopy or use the free version of the bulk insert extension.