# MsSQL not passing user defined table type using sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-types

I'm trying to pass my User Defined Table Type to a store procedure (originaly using EF). However, I'm stuck, because it looks like sp_executesql passes the parametr to the stored procedure, but its empty. Check it out, here is the type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[BigIntList] AS TABLE(
    [Item] [bigint] NULL
)
```

Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
    @bookEntryIds [dbo].[BigIntList] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    SELECT * FROM @bookEntryIds
END
```

And here is what bothers me:

```
DECLARE @bookEntryIds [dbo].[BigIntList]
INSERT INTO @bookEntryIds VALUES (50181)
INSERT INTO @bookEntryIds VALUES (40182)

-- 1. This returns 50181 and 40182
EXEC [dbo].[MyProcedure] @bookEntryIds

-- 2. This returns empty result with column "Item"
EXEC sp_executesql N'[dbo].[MyProcedure]', N'@bookEntryIds [dbo].[BigIntList] READONLY', @bookEntryIds
```

The second query is used by Entity Framework, so I need it to work. Could you please tell me what is wrong with it? I checked with several guides how to do this and I see nothing wrong here.

I tried changing the type to string (VARCHAR(100)), but the result was the same. I'm running it on SQL server 2016, but the same happens on dev (hosting) machine, where is 2014 version.

Thanks for help.

Martin

EDIT - Solution by @sepupic:

If you were inspired by [Pass table value type to SQL Server stored procedure via Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772886/pass-table-value-type-to-sql-server-stored-procedure-via-entity-framework) like me, please, make sure you are passing the parameter (!), like:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("[dbo].[MyProcedure] @bookEntryIds", parameter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> -- 2. This returns empty result with column "Item"
> EXEC sp_executesql N'[dbo].[MyProcedure]', N'@bookEntryIds [dbo].[BigIntList] READONLY', @bookEntryIds
> ```

The result is empty because you forgot to pass in the parameter, it should look like this:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'[dbo].[MyProcedure] @bookEntryIds = @bookEntryIds', N'@bookEntryIds [dbo].[BigIntList] READONLY', @bookEntryIds
```

Comment: For maximum `@bookEntryIds` goodness, the full form of the statement would be `EXEC sp_executesql N'EXEC [dbo].[MyProcedure] @bookEntryIds = @bookEntryIds', N'@bookEntryIds [dbo].[BigIntList] READONLY', @bookEntryIds = @bookEntryIds`. This also makes it clear that we're calling the stored procedure in a very roundabout way, as a dynamic `EXEC` SQL statement. A direct RPC call would pass the parameters without indirection, but I don't know if EF has direct support for that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I feel really stupid. I probably missed it because I was inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772886/pass-table-value-type-to-sql-server-stored-procedure-via-entity-framework, where it is also missing. Thanks again.