# MSSQL split string function performance terrible

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two separate queries/methods and functions so that I can pass two strings in my stored procedures which basically look like this:

```
1234,12346,12690812,1259081 => UPCList parameter

1234,12346,12690812,1259081 => EANList parameter
```

Now the first method looks like following:

```
create procedure [dbo].[zsp_selectallupceans_list]
(
@UPCList nvarchar(4000),
@EANList nvarchar(4000),
@Type tinyint
)
as

select DISTINCT dd.UPC,dd.EAN,dd.EBAYID as ItemID
from ThirdPartyData  as dd 
where dd.UPC in (SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitString(@UPCList)) OR
dd.EAN in (SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitString(@EANList)) and dd.Type=@Type
```

Combined with splitstring function created in MSSQL:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[splitstring] ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

And now the second method:

```
create procedure [dbo].[zsp_selectallupceans_listProduction]
(
@UPCList nvarchar(4000),
@EANList nvarchar(4000),
@Type tinyint
)
as


SELECT  dd.UPC,dd.EAN,dd.EBAYID as ItemID
from ThirdPartyData  as dd 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.SplitStringProduction(@UPCList,',') S1 WHERE dd.UPC=S1.val) 
   OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.SplitStringProduction(@EANList,',') S2 WHERE dd.EAN=S2.val) and dd.Type=@Type
```

And now the second method splitstringProduction:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStringProduction]
(
  @string nvarchar(max),
  @delimiter nvarchar(5)
) RETURNS @t TABLE
(
  val nvarchar(500)
)
AS
BEGIN
  declare @xml xml
  set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@string,@delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

  insert into @t(val)
  select 
    r.value('.','varchar(500)') as item
  from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)

  RETURN
END
```

And now here comes the weird part... Benchmark results of both methods come up like this:

```
  var findEans = ctx.zsp_selectallupceans_list(formedList.UPCList, formedList.EANList, 1).ToList();
//Execution time 4.8 seconds

 var findEans = ctx.zsp_selectallupceans_listProduction(formedList.UPCList, formedList.EANList, 1).ToList();
//Execution time: 15 seconds
```

As far as my understanding goes, the second method should perform much faster than first... But this is not the case... Not only is the performance for the 2nd method worse, it is  more than 3 times execution time than the first... And I cannot understand why ...

What is going on here guys? What would be the best method to reduce the execution time to <1 second?

Can someone help me out here please?

Comment: What did performance look like when you benchmarked purely using SQL Server (i.e. in Management Studio rather than C#)?

Comment: Try Jeff Moden's [splitter function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/), or if you're on SQL2016 or later then try [Split_String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - either one should perform better

Comment: Why are you passing lists as a single string and parsing it? Have you considered alternative approaches to string splitting?

Comment: Yes. Use Table Valued Parameters. String-splitting for multiple (list-like) parameters is a nasty smell. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772886/pass-table-value-type-to-sql-server-stored-procedure-via-entity-framework

Comment: The method you have there is RBAR (Row-by-Agonising-Row), something that SQl Server, and many other DBMS perform very poorly at. SQL Server excels at data-set operations. @Mazhar has linked 2 very good alternatives which will perform far far better, and if you're on SQL Server 2012/2014 you could make use of [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2012/106903/).

Comment: how does the string get to be there?  Are you sending it from an application layer?  If using .net (for example) you've got much better string manipulation classes in it, such as string builder - hey you can use .net on SQL server, I've never done that though.

Comment: @Mazhar I read that string_split cannot be used... ?