# LINQ method with multiple conditions and combinations

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq

Let's say I have a List of Detail class with 1000 entries. How can I exactly retrieve the matching data from the database Details table using LINQ method with a combination of both FirstCode and SecondCode properties?

```
public class Detail
{
  public string FirstCode  { get; set; }
  public string SecondCode { get; set; }
}
```

If we're going to retrieve a single data it would be like this:

```
foreach(var detail in details)
{
    var retrievedData = context.Details
        .Where(x => x.FirstCode == detail.FirstCode && x.SecondCode == detail.SecondCode)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    // Add to some list here
}
```

But I don't want to fetch 1000 times from the database, also I don't want to get all data from Details table and then do the searching within the .NET level, because it's not ideal if we have bunch of data(for ex. 500,000+ records in Details table).

Comment: Your `Where()` clause will generate the proper SQL statement that would only return the relevant rows from the database. That's the purpose of Linq-to-Entities (which is part of EntityFramework).

Comment: Join Your Details with details based on detail.Firstcode and detail.SecondCode and retrieve final result at once

Comment: I *think* what you are saying is that the `details` collection has `1000` or more items in it which causes that many trips to the database due to the `foreach` clause which you are trying to avoid? Where is `details` being populated? Is `details` a user fed list (input) *or* is this retrieved from the database immediately before the loop? Show more code.

Comment: Is it possible really?

Comment: @Igor yes, is there a way for me to do a one time call, getting that 1000 records from the 500,000+ records in the database?

Comment: @xird - Possibly but you have to answer my question first otherwise any offered solution is just a guess.

Comment: @Igor the details list is user input

Comment: Are you using Sql Server as backend or something else (if so please specify the rdbms)

Comment: @Igor Yes, SQL server

Comment: Why do you want to query your database for 2000 values? Can't you insert those values in a temp table, and select the data you want using a join?

Comment: You have 2 options. You can use a [table valued parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8157345/1260204) ([example2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33773336/1260204)), this is more code but will be more performant if you are using indexes on these values because it would result in the use of an index seek. Or you can concatenate the values (first+second) in the lookup and create a string array and the use `Contains` and concatenate the values in the database table as the input of the contains call. This is easier to do but is less performant because it essentially results in a table scan.

Comment: I'm with CodeCaster here. Trying to write a query with 2000 filter values is massive, and strongly suggests that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The proposed solution (Y) is not good, and you should instead ask about the X problem you seek to solve.

Comment: Are you EF core or EF6?

Answer (score 2):

You need to programmatically generate the 'where' clause. Start with a query that returns all the rows in the *Details* database table...

```
IQueryable<XDetail> queryable = (from d in context.Details select d);
```

...where XDetail is the class type of the database table. I assume it is different from the *Detail* class in your question. Now you need to generate all the clauses to the query that specify the list of entries we want...

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<XDetail>();
foreach(Detail d in details)
    predicate = predicate.Or((xd) => xd.FirstCode == d.FirstCode && 
                                     xd.SecondCode == d.SecondCode));

queryable = queryable.Where(predicate);
var results = queryable.ToList();
```

You can see the code for the PredicateBuilder class [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). Note that Entity Framework will generate the required SQL but there is a limit to how big that query can be. So adding 1000 clauses will certainly make it to big. You would have to experiment but you might be limited to a 100 or less before you hit the limit.

Comment: super useful! (maybe you can also add the PredicateBuilder to the answer)